# Columns on sql Triggers (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want that if when inserting 'zone' is null, the trigger will be fired and change the zone value from 'null' to 'sin', I think the problem is in the if.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZONA_JUGADOR
    BEFORE INSERT ON EQUIPOS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.ZONA = NULL THEN
    :NEW.ZONA:='SIN';
    END IF;

END;
```

The insert sentence I'm doing:

```
VALUES ('eq47','01826247G','Miranda',NULL);
```

Comment: @Littlefoot edited, The problem is in the if comparison, but I don't know what it is

Comment: Right; now I understand. I posted an answer with an example; have a look, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `IF`. `NULL` isn't "equal" to something, so you can't use

```
if :new.zona = null
```

but

```
if :new.zona IS NULL
```

---

Anyway, perhaps you'd rather use `NVL` function:

```
SQL> create table equipos (id varchar2(10), zona varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger zona_jugador
  2    before insert on equipos
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.zona := nvl(:new.zona, 'SIN');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into equipos(id, zona) values ('ba12', 'zona');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into equipos(id, zona) values ('eq47', null);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From equipos;

ID         ZONA
---------- ----------
ba12       zona
eq47       SIN

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh i hadn't thought of using nvl, thanks for both options!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do the null check as part of the trigger definition (rather than body) using a `when` clause:

```
create or replace trigger zona_jugador
  before insert on equipos
  for each row
  when (new.zona is null)
begin
  :new.zona := 'SIN';
end;
/
```

Note that `when` refers to `new` not `:new`. And it's still `is null` not `= null`, as @Littlefoot explained, and as [shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html).

The result is the same, but in some situations this may perform better as the trigger doesn't have to fire when there is nothing to do, saving context switches between SQL and PL/SQL. You'd probably need to be doing some pretty intensive operations on large amounts of data to actually notice the difference, but still, it all adds up.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0de635b2c778ee02075120ed40a1cb21) borrowing @Littlefoot's set-up.